# Parsing webserver JSON Values to data property

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, chart.js

I am trying to use the JSON values from a file on a hosted webserver and believe I am parsing the values correctly and using them within my [Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) arrays, but for some reason I am getting error messages that I can't quite debug.

error 1: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h`

code reference: `var gaValues = JSON.parse(url);`

error 2: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

code reference: `labels: [ga:dayOfWeekName],`

JSON:

```
{"kind": "analytics#gaData", "rows": [["Friday", "2"], ["Monday", "3"], ["Saturday", "0"], ["Sunday", "1"], ["Thursday", "4"], ["Tuesday", "4"], ["Wednesday", "4"]], "containsSampledData": false, "profileInfo": {"webPropertyId": "UA-22222-1", "internalWebPropertyId": "222222", "tableId": "ga:22222", "profileId": "2222", "profileName": "All Web Site Data", "accountId": "222222"}, "itemsPerPage": 50, "id": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:222222&dimensions=ga:dayOfWeekName&metrics=ga:sessions&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&max-results=50", "totalResults": 7, "query": {"max-results": 50, "dimensions": "ga:dayOfWeekName", "start-date": "7daysAgo", "start-index": 1, "ids": "ga:22222", "metrics": ["ga:sessions"], "end-date": "yesterday"}, "totalsForAllResults": {"ga:sessions": "18"}, "columnHeaders": [{"dataType": "STRING", "columnType": "DIMENSION", "name": "ga:dayOfWeekName"}, {"dataType": "INTEGER", "columnType": "METRIC", "name": "ga:sessions"}], "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:22222&dimensions=ga:dayOfWeekName&metrics=ga:sessions&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&max-results=50"}
```

charts-options.js:

```
    var url = 'https://test.appspot.com/query?id=ahJzfmNvbm5vcnBoaWxsaXBzMjtetssesestestststRyFQsSCEFwaVF1ZXJ5GICAgICAgIAKDA';

    var gaValues = JSON.parse(url);

    var barChartdata = {
        labels: [ga:dayOfWeekName],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [gaValues.ga:sessions]
            }
        ]
    };


    var options = {

        //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
        scaleBeginAtZero : true,

        //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
        scaleShowGridLines : true,

        //String - Colour of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

        //Number - Width of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineWidth : 1,

        //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
        barShowStroke : true,

        //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
        barStrokeWidth : 2,

        //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
        barValueSpacing : 5,

        //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
        barDatasetSpacing : 1,

        //Boolean - Set if responsive or not
        responsive : true

    }

window.onload = function(){

    // Get the context of the canvas element
    var ctx = document.getElementById("sessions-graph").getContext("2d");
    var sessionsGraph = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartdata, options); //Create a chart with "data" array

};
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Google Super Proxy Test</title>

        <script src="chart-options.js"></script>
         <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>

    <div style="width: 50%">
        <canvas id="sessions-graph" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are not writing valid javascript. Also, [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) only accepts JSON strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.parse` expects a json string, not an URL you need to load the data yourself i.e. using XMLHTTPRequest. Despite the fact that `gaValues` is undefined, you also need to access object keys containing special characters using the following notation:

```
gaValues["ga:sessions"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse URL in your code at line `var gaValues = JSON.parse(url);`
The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON. You need to pass your response as parameter not URL.